What is the expansion of (1+x)^n where n = rational number & |x|>1.
I was doing a math question which required use of expansion. I found this information:

What if |x|>1? And what is the expansion of (x+y)^n where n is not necessarily a natural number? Do we have a formula for that?

If $|x|>1$, then you can write $(1+x)^n=x^n(1+x^{-1})^n$. At that point, $|x^{-1}|=|x|^{-1}<1$ and thus you can expand in powers of $x^{-1}$ instead.

If $x < -1$ and $n$ is not integral, you may end up with a complex value.

As semiclassical explained, for $|x|>1$,
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^n &= x^n(1+x^{-1})^n
\\ &=
x^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}(x^{-1})^k\right)
\\ &=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k}
\end{align}$$
This infinite series converges (by the ratio test).
Notation:
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}
$$
Here, $n$ need not be an integer.

Brian's complex value when $x<-1$:  that occurs in the $x^n$ factor, but the convergent series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}(x^{-1})^k$ is real.
